# Phonebook email property return nil while loading in UITableView

Tags: iphone

In my sample application. I have to fetch all contacts from my iPhone and display each one's firstName, lastName, companyName, and email address.

I have written code from Apple reference guide, but face some problems while loading contacts in UITableView.

I have retrieved all contacts using the code below:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                                           kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                                           people
                                                           );


CFArraySortValues(
                  peopleMutable,
                  CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
                  (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
                  (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()
                  );

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(people);
CFRelease(peopleMutable);


ABRecordRef record = [peopleMutable objectAtIndex:i];
ABMultiValueRef emails = (ABMultiValueRef) ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSLog(@"ABMultiValueGetCount %d",ABMultiValueGetCount(emails));
if(ABMultiValueGetCount(emails))
       emailID = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
```

When I use this line of code in `viewdidAppear` it works fine. But when i use this same method in the UITableViewDelegate method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. It didn't return email address.

Has anyone seen a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that `peopleMutable` is nil when you access it from `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because you load your data later then tableView reload its data.

Call `[tableView reloadData]` after populating `peopleMutable` array.

Comment: Yes i tried.But didn't get email .One more info is the firstname,lastname,companyname all are displayed correctly in the tableview .Except email address.